# Retrieving objects from a binary search tree

Tags: java, search, compareto

For a class exercise I am to implement a binary search tree in Java. Each tree node contains the usual left and right pointers plus a "payload" object. I've implemented compareTo() for searching the tree; it uses a unique integer ID field in each payload object to do the comparison.

The question is, what do I compare it to? When I want to search for a given payload object, do I create a "dummy" object that has just the integer value I'm looking for, with the rest of its fields being irrelevant or undefined? This seems kind of awkward and ad hoc.

Comment: This site isn't meant for us to do your homework for you. Please show some code and some effort before you submit a question here.

Comment: You could make your code do whatever you want. Choose something that works. Don't forget that the arguments to a method can be of whatever type you want.